# Updating a Value in a Another Form (Zoho Creator)

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge

I am able to retrieve data from another form/report, but I am not able to update the value and save back in the other form.

For the example below, I am trying to get the vacation_days_taken by user and then add new vacation days and update the vacation_days_taken in the employee_form. But, I get an Improper Statement error.

Can someone please show me how I can update/edit other forms while working with a different one?

```
daysOff = Employee_Form[ID == input.Employee_Name].Vacation_Days_Taken;
if(input.Number_of_Days_Requested + daysOff < 20)
{
     Employee_Form[ID == input.Employee_Name].Vacation_Days_Taken = input.Number_of_Days_Requested + daysOff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this on Zoho Creator. We understand that you are trying to use "fetch records" to update the leaves taken by the employee, but you need to use "update record" task instead. I have also used two forms -- Employee form and Leave Request form.

The first step would be to create a collection variable(employeeRec) and fetch records from the Employee form.

```
employeeRec = Employee_form[ID == input.Employee_Name];
```

Fetch the record of that particular employee and store in a collection variable(employeeRec)

```
daysOff = employeeRec.Vacation_Days_Taken;
```

Then let's fetch the Vacation_Days_Taken and assign it to another variable daysOff. After which use the IF condition to verify and update the Vacation_Days_Taken.

```
if(daysOff + input.No_of_days_requested < 20)
{
    employeeRec.Vacation_Days_Taken=daysOff + input.No_of_days_requested;
}
```

Hope this code works for you.

Comment: I tried what you mentioned, but still not working. I have added the code in "On Edit" -> "On Success" and below is my code:

Comment: if(input.Status == "Approved")
{
 employeeForm = Employee_Form[ID == input.Employee_Name];
 daysOff=employeeForm.Vacation_Days_Taken;
 info daysOff;
 daysTaken=input.Number_of_Days_Requested + daysOff;
 info employeeForm.Vacation_Days_Taken;
 employeeForm.Vacation_Days_Taken=daysTaken;
 sendmail
 [
  from:zoho.adminuserid
  to:Employee_Form[ID == input.Employee_Name].email
  subject:"Your Request Has Been Approved"
 ...

Answer (score 1):

In the second code snippet that you have provided here and claimed not working. I see two issues.

1. The employee form collection being inside the status check block.
2. There is no check being performed to find if the no of leaves have exceeded 20 or not.

   ```
   employeeForm = Employee_Form[ID == input.Employee_Name]; // I have moved this assignment outside the if check meant for approved status. If this line is included inside the if check and if the status is not approved, then the employeeForm would not be available, which might cause issues.

   if(input.Status == "Approved") {
     daysOff=employeeForm.Vacation_Days_Taken; 
     daysTaken=input.Number_of_Days_Requested + daysOff;

     // This check is missing
     if(daystaken < 20){
       employeeForm.Vacation_Days_Taken=daysTaken;
       sendmail 
       [from:zoho.adminuserid
        to:Employee_Form[ID == input.Employee_Name].email
        subject:"Your Request Has Been Approved"
        ....
       ]
     }
   }
   ```
3. I also see that you have added this for the trigger **On Edit -> On Success**. Which means this is supposed to be executed after the submit is complete. If you want to execute this script after validating, then this block should be **On Edit -> On Validate**. And if the count exceeds 20, then a **cancel submit** can be effected to disallow submitting the record.

Please try all of these out and in case you still face issues, please tell us what exactly is failing / not working with error messages or discrepancies in values, etc.